# Copy one column to another based on a Criteria (MS Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I've Two sheets, Sheet1, Sheet2

Sheet1:

```
A   | B
-----
123 |
456 |
789 |
```

Sheet 2:

```
A   | B
-----
123 | DATA1
789 | DATA2
456 | DATA3
```

I want The Sheet1 to have the following output:

```
A   | B
-----
123 | DATA1
456 | DATA3
789 | DATA2
```

I have a very basic VB knowledge, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sheet1, cell B1: `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,0)` and drag down should give the desired result

Edit (VBA solution):
`Sheet1.Range("B1:B3").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$3,2,0)"`