# How to search a sheet for a word or phrase?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing the macro to search for a phrase, select the cell to the right, copy, select page 2 and then paste to a static cell there. The macro is for organizing restaurant sales reports on an Excel spreadsheet.

I'm new to programming and have no experience with VBA.

I cannot figure out how to search a sheet for a word or phrase.

Comment: Have a look at the `VLOOKUP` function, no macro is needed:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314053/copy-one-column-to-another-based-on-a-criteria-ms-excel/18314111#18314111

Comment: Record a macro while you find, Ctrl+f, the information, keeping the options in mind, then using an activecell.offset to get your data.

Comment: I forgot to include that the generated sales reports are not always structured the same due to week to week changes. Because of this I did not think recording the macro with clicks or relying on the row/column  numbers would work. That is why I thought a search function is my only option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to find a cell, it depends what you are trying to do.

To do exactly what you are describing you would use the `Range.Find` method.

#### Example of `Range.Find`

In a new Workbook I write words such as cat and dog in random cells.

Then I create a new module with a public sub as such:

```
Public Sub TestFind()
  Sheet1.Cells _
    .Find("cat", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False) _
    .Offset(-1, 1) _
    .Copy Sheet2.[A1]
End Sub
```

Okay, to explain. If you aren't familiar, in VBA you can have [named and optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251503.aspx) which I've used above. I've also used some [line continuations or as microsoft calls them "line breaks"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa163834%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

`Sheet1.Cells` On Sheet1 I'm taking the Cells range (all the cells) and calling that range's Find method.

`.Find` returns the first range containing the word cat anywhere in the cell (upper and lower case doesnt matter because of the `MatchCase:=False`, and `LookAt:=xlPart` means any part of the cell's contents, where `LookAt:=xlWhole` would mean the entire cell).

`.Offset(-1,1)` means get the range or cell one up and one to the right of the found cell.

`.Copy Sheet2.[A1]` the `.[A1]` syntax is the same as writing `.Range("A1")`. I hope it's obvious what this copy statement does.

#### Other methods

You could also look at doing something similar to a VLOOKUP or INDEX and MATCH. Or maybe use one of the sort or filter interfaces. It depends how your workbook is structured and what you want to do.